# how to set Date object to specific value

Tags: javascript, html, angular

i have the below posted two methods. the problem is when i try to set the month to a specific value in methons `onDateChangedDateOfSpray` as shown below, the date with id `idDateOfApproval` gets changed accordingly.
i want to set the date to specific value in method `onDateChangedDateOfSpray` so that it does not affect the date with id `idDateOfApproval`
please let me know how to achieve that

**code**:

```
private onDateChangedDateOfSpray(event:any):void {
    console.log("event: ", event)
    console.log("this.iDatePasser.dateOfSpray: ", this.iDatePasser.dateOfSpray)
    console.log(new Date(event).getMonth())
    let d = new Date(this.iDatePasser.dateOfSpray);
    d.setMonth(11)
    this.iDatePasser.dateOfSpray = this.datepipe.transform(d, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}

private onDateChangedDateOfApproval(event:any):void {
    console.log("event: ", event)
    console.log("this.iDatePasser.dateOfApproval: ", this.iDatePasser.dateOfApproval)
    console.log(new Date(event).getMonth())
```

}

**html**:

```
<div id=idDateOfPesticideSpray class="date">Date:
                    <input  type="date" id="idDataOfSpray" [(ngModel)]="iDatePasser.dateOfSpray" (ngModelChange)="onDateChangedDateOfSpray($event)" name="trip-start"
                        value="2021-07-21"
                        min="2021-01-01" max="2090-12-31">
                </div>
                
                <div id=idDateOfApproval class="date">Date of approval:
                    <input  type="date" id="dateOfApproval" [(ngModel)]="iDatePasser.dateOfApproval" (ngModelChange)="onDateChangedDateOfApproval($event)" name="trip-start"
                        value="2021-07-21"
                        min="2021-01-01" max="2090-12-31">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have just to change the name attribute because it is similar in both of them

**code**:

```
<div id=idDateOfPesticideSpray class="date">Date:
                    <input  type="date" id="idDataOfSpray" [(ngModel)]="iDatePasser.dateOfSpray" (ngModelChange)="onDateChangedDateOfSpray($event)" name="dateOfSpray"
                        value="2021-07-21"
                        min="2021-01-01" max="2090-12-31">
                </div>
                <div id=idDateOfApproval class="date">Date of approval:
                    <input  type="date" id="dateOfApproval" [(ngModel)]="iDatePasser.dateOfApproval" (ngModelChange)="onDateChangedDateOfApproval($event)" name="DateOfApproval"
                        value="2021-07-21"
                        min="2021-01-01" max="2090-12-31">
                </div>
                
                :
                    <input  type="date" id="dateOfApproval" [(ngModel)]="iDatePasser.dateOfApproval" (ngModelChange)="onDateChangedDateOfApproval($event)" name="DateOfApproval"
                        value="2021-07-21"
                        min="2021-01-01" max="2090-12-31">
                </div>
```